# Get value from checkbox - 0 when unchecked, 1 when checked

Tags: php, html

I need to get value 1 - when checkbox is checked and 0, when it is unchecked.

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[color][]" class="color" value="1" checked>
```

Data array - stores other data that is retrieved from `input` type `text` and `select`. It's working fine. The problem occurs when I try to retrieve data from an `input` of type `checkbox`. Brief description of the "project": the script is to add several records to the database simultaneously. To start with, one section is available for data entry, for a single record - using JS after clicking the appropriate button - the next section appears and so on up to a certain maximum number of sections/possible records. In general, the script works correctly - records are added. The problem is with the color column that gets the data from the aforementioned checkbox. After the form is submitted - there is a reorganization of the board to somehow present this more reasonably.
PHP code:

```php
foreach($data as $columnName => $columnValues){
        foreach($columnValues as $rowIndex => $columnValue){
            $result[$rowIndex][$columnName] = $columnValue;
        }
}
```

To get at the value:

```php
foreach($result as $r => $value){
    if(isset($value['color'])){
        $color = 1;
    } else {
        $color = 0;
    }
}
```

While with the number of records <= 2 it works correctly, when there are > 2 values are not assigned correctly. What am I doing wrong? If you need more information - please write. I seem to have pasted everything related to this.

When using `var_dump` for `$value['color']` with 4 records there is this result:

```
string(1) "1"
string(1) "1"
NULL
NULL
```

Where only the first and fourth checkbox was checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike input type *text* and *select*, only checked *checkbox* inputs will be submitted.  So using dynamic arrays `[]`, if you have 3 and only the first is checked, then it will be submitted as `$_POST['data']['color'][0]`.  If you only check the third one it will also be submitted as `$_POST['data']['color'][0]`, etc...  With the current code there is no way to track them.

Probably the best way to do this is to use a hidden input with the same name before the checkbox with value `0` as default, so that all checkboxes are submitted, either with `0` or `1`.  You need to specify the numerical indexes for each:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="data[color][0]" value="0">
 <input type="checkbox" name="data[color][0]" class="color" value="1" checked>

 <input type="hidden" name="data[color][1]" value="0">
 <input type="checkbox" name="data[color][1]" class="color" value="1" checked>

 <input type="hidden" name="data[color][2]" value="0">
 <input type="checkbox" name="data[color][2]" class="color" value="1" checked>
```

Now you'll always get 3 `$_POST['data']['color']` elements, either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Now I understand how it works. Unfortunately I can't use array indexes in HTML code, because it's possible to add another section, but also remove it, so the index can change or even duplicate itself (with a simple variable that is incremented when adding a section and decremented when removing a section, I can't solve this in JS.

Comment: However, if I do not use indexes then the structure of the array changes. And the values from the checkbox are still wrong (except for the initial 2 sections). Preview for 3 sections (checked is in first and last): [0] => [[color] => 1 /* And other data*/]], [1] => [[color] => 0 /* And other data*/], [2] => [[color] => 0 /* And other data*/], <- wrong 
And where is this from? [3] => [[color] => 1], [4] => [[color] => 0],

Comment: In this situation, I think it would be better to use `select` with a YES/NO option. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your specific answer.